# how to use achart engine in android

Tags: android, achartengine

can you please post a basic example of using achart engine in android

Answer (score 7):

I know this has been more than a year since the question was asked, but I'd like to try to help any others who have the same question and find this as I did.

I have managed to get the ChartDemo.java down to just a few lines and it completely skips the GeneratedChartDemo.java.  The result calls just the SensorValuesChart().  This is what I was interested in but the call can be changed to any of the others, except the hard coded ones, that you would wish to try.

```
package org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo;
import org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.SensorValuesChart;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ChartDemo extends ListActivity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
      startActivity((new SensorValuesChart()).execute(this));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you at least try?

http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html follow that guide. The zip referenced ( http://achartengine.googlecode.com/files/achartengine-0.6.0-demo-source.zip ) has a ton of source code. Googling also gets you some sample results.

Comment: These are hardly basic, due to a quite complex nature of the demo app. Multiple classes calling each other to create views.

Comment: @piotrek - Nope, but that's the nature of achart engine in general. It's a messy library that I would avoid - Steema TeeChart is amazing.

Comment: There are no sample results on Google. I think you have to just run the demo, choose the graph demo you like(there is a whole list), and then try to understand that code. I will post my sampled code once finished.

Comment: The next best is another page on Stack Overflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a

Pretty lame response, Klaus. Even looking at the AChartEngine's sample code, it's not easy to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Linking to this thread, which explains more about using AChartEngine with intents vs. with views directly.

[Android: I am using AChartEngine library for graphs, but not able to integrate achartengine's graph view with android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a)