# How to use achartEngine?

Tags: android, view, charts, achartengine

I'm trying to make some graphics in my application with the `AchartEngine API` but it doesn't works.

Can anyone explain me how to have a view with a `graphic` instead of `Intent`?

Cause in the demo code it's only by `Intent`, not by view.

edit: 
I tried to test the 2 options at the same time:
I have a linearLayout with a button in it:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/list_infos_layout_stat" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/list_infos_bouton_stats"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="statistiques"
/>
```

When I hit the button, a new activity is made by the `ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(..)` method and it works great.

And in the same LinearLayout, I put a view returned by `ChartFactory.getLineChartView` method, its ok I have the graphic at the right of the button.
But when I remove the button I have nothing...

```
View graphique = new ReponsesChart().getView(contexte);
        if (graphique !=null){
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_infos_layout_stat);
            layout.addView(graphique, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        } else {
            Log.d("Infos", "GRAPHIQUE NULL");
        }
```

edit 2: Fixed by replacing Fill Parent properties when I add the view to the layout by the width of the screen

Comment: Have a look at [I am using AChartEngine...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-ac)

Comment: Thanks but i already tried it, but i doesn't works ( post edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ChartFactory class there are several methods that you can use like this:

```
    GraphicalView gView=ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartView(context,data,renderer);
```

and similar ones for other graph types like line charts and bar charts. You can then simply call:

```
    setContentView(gView);
```

Download the documentation for AChartEngine, its pretty easy to find there.

Comment: For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a

Answer (score 0):

Would something that writes to a bitmap help? I use the following in some of my code:

```
final XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multipleRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
final XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
multipleRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

final XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = final XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = ...

final Bitmap image1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);    
final TimeChart tc = new TimeChart(dataset, multipleRenderer);

final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image1);
tc.draw(canvas, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, paint);
final Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image1, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

Note that I've cut out a lot of code relating to initialising the multipleRender and dataset

Comment: I think this answer possibly made more sense as an answer before the question was edited, but I'll leave it for now in case I'm misunderstanding the intent of the edit.