# How to integrate ACHARTENGINE in my LAYOUT?

Tags: android, achartengine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: I am using AChartEngine library for graphs, but not able to integrate achartengine’s graph view with android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a)

I am new to ACHARTENGINE and want to integrate it in my layout.

Below is my XML:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/report_description"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="300dip"
android:layout_gravity="top">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="1" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and This is my code :

```
public class GraphScreen extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.graph);
}
}
```

Can you please help me to render any chart BAR, PIE or LINE

Thanks in advance
Madz

Answer (score 1):

You can see [ACHARTENGINE goodies](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html)  and download source of samples. 
So, [This question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a)