# NoClassDefFoundError requestfactory with Android connected app engine project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, requestfactory

04-02 21:45:18.260: E/AndroidRuntime(17850): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.capstonecontrol.client.ModulesRequestFactory

Is the error I get when ever my android app tries to use any request factory object.  Everything was working until I updated the plugins for eclipse and now I cant seem to get anything to work.  Eclipse was giving me an error about my requestfactory-apt.jar file so I removed it from the factory path and added the jar again and that cleared the compile error.  But now I get the error above.

I even tried to create a whole new android linked app engine project and just test out the default app and I get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886634/issue-in-achartengine-jar-file/9886768#9886768)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new ADT tools require the external jar files to be placed within a folder called "libs" at the root of your project.

Once you move your external libraries there, they will be automatically detected by the tools, included in your build path and your application will work as normal.

Comment: solarnz, are you saying to move the "requestfactory-apt.jar" file to the .../project-android/lib directory? If so, doing this hasn't worked for me, even though I have the same symptoms as user1309358

Comment: @aez it needs to be "libs" not "lib". This directory should be located at the root of your android project.