# achartengine demo compiling, but runtime error

Tags: android, achartengine

I followed demo instructions on page http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html

i successfully imported the demo project, but every chart give throws
a `NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime, similar to this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset
```

**achartengine-1.0.0.jar** is on build path, and it is reported under
'Referenced Libraries'. I guess this is a newbie problem, but I
decided to report it since I just imported the demo project *'as is'*
and tried to run it on my phone.

Do I need other steps, not listed on 'goodies' page?

Comment: I have detailed every steps to include AChartEngineHere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17951760/656600

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found a good answer on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/achartengine/TLHv3a08GdA), tested it and it seems to be working:

The only thing that I have ever came across in this case is the **export of the jar** ... if that makes sense.

In Eclipse:

1. Right click your project - go to build path - select Configure build
   path
2. go to the "Order and Export" tab
3. Check the "achartengine-1.0.0.jar box and then single click its name
4. move it up so its right below the Android dependancies (sometimes this can make a difference if you have multiple Jars)

click ok then clean your project. (Project -> Clean...)

Answer (score 4):

Remind to **change the "lib" directory to "libs" first** !

Then CHECK the box of `achartengine-1.0.0.jar`  and move it over the Android Dependencies in the "Configure build path" - "Order and Export" tab"！

Answer (score 1):

The error (`NoClassDefFoundError`) you are seeing is runtime error. Referenced library solves only compile time error not runtime error. Add those jars to lib folder of your project. Those jars should be available at runtime also.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from 'Shine' worked with the addition of removing import of `android.R` from `PieChartBuilder` and removing two `@Overrides` from `PieChartBuilder` and `XY_ChartBuilder`before Eclipse would agree to compile.

Answer (score -1):

You need simply to add your jar files to the Libraries folder. It should work fine.