# achartengine demo , no trace of R file

Tags: android, eclipse, achartengine

I am trying to run achartengine demo source on my computer.
I correctly import the zipfile(achartengine-1.0.0-demo-source.zip) into my workspace as a project.
there is no gen folder at all.

and I checked; there are **no** "import Android.R" lines.

Then nearly every import line or method gets the "cannot be resolved" error.
There is a line in the project explorer menu saying "unable to get system library for the project"
I dunno what to do with that either.

So Eclipse suggests that I import Android.jar to my project and I do that.
everything seems to be ok but there remains one problem.

There is still error in lines like this

import "org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.R;"

Yes! Still, There exists no gen folder, thus no R file.

I know a R file has been imported within the android package but I cannot delete it.
Also I checked and all my resources and xml names are **lowercase**.

Can anybody help me please? :)

Comment: Also tried cleaning the project, no luck with that!

Comment: Try to clean your project. Project > clean .This may help you.

Comment: organize imports in your activity then clean your project and then restart eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had the same problem. Solved. Do not import zip file.
Extract zip file and import as existing project.

Plus you may run into error with @override statements: can be solved by setting compatibility to 1.6 level [Java 7 language features with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android)

Plus you may run into error during demo runtime  - the solution here (see post by Shine) [achartengine demo compiling, but runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433847/achartengine-demo-compiling-but-runtime-error)

Answer (score 1):

The R class and the gen directory are generated automatically by Eclipse, if you have the ADT plugin installed. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160778/the-application-achartengine-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again/10496375#10496375) as it may help you setup the project correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone,there was something mainly necessary.

I had to change my **lib** folder to **libs**.