# AChartEngine Runtime Error, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, achartengine

in my Project, i had added the achartengine library.

I can compile the Application, but if I want to start the Activity, where I use this library, i get this error

```
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset
```

I followed the solution in this thread: **[achartengine demo compiling, but runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433847/achartengine-demo-compiling-but-runtime-error/19891940#19891940)** 
but I can't fix it, because i use **Android-Studio**, not Eclipse and I don't know how i can deploy this solution to android-studio.
Could anyone help? :(

Comment: Post the code of yours which raises this Exception.

Comment: Okay i have the solution... here at this page: http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1gb6s2/android_studio_noclassdeffounderror_still_trying/

>Basically, open a command prompt (or terminal) and navigate to your project directory. Use the following command on Windows:

**gradlew.bat clean**

Then reload Android Studio and try again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit late...
Try to open a terminal, navigate to your projects location and type "gradlew.bat clean", that worked pretty well for me.