# How to create Dial Chart in android?

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

I am trying to create a Dial Chart in android. I used the achartengine since I saw in their GitHub page that they have a DialChart. While implementing I was faced with this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105509/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-achartengine-model-categoryseries-error-in-a).

After doing some research I came to know that the chart I was trying to create and the one provided by the AChartEngine are different.

The chart that I am trying to create is

[image: Dial Chart]

Is there any Charting Engine that renders these kind of charts or is there any tutorial that teaches to implement using graphic functions?

While you are at it if you can solve this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105509/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-achartengine-model-categoryseries-error-in-a) it is appreciated..

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart  
Combining it with some custom tweaks should make rendering such a chart possible

Comment: "any tutorial that teaches to implement using graphic functions". It's all in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html You have to literally draw everything directly yourself.