# How to use one activity inside another activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Just I have created graph chart using [Chart Engine Android](http://www.achartengine.org/index.html)
I have used data from my database to use value for chart.
Now I have one activity which is main to display graph chart with left menu options.
So Whenever i am calling chart activity its going to show its own activity sepratly.
I want to embed that chart activity with my main activity with left menu options.
Is it possible? I am using android 4.0
How to solve this task? Please help me friends.

Comment: Finally found answer on this link which i am looking for:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your application would benefit from using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) The developer site has some very good information you should read.

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed an Activity into another in Android, as Activities are meant to be independent objects.

Since android 3.0, you can use Fragments, which are Activities sub-elements, which you can combine in many different way. For example having your Activity using one left fragment to display a list of items and a right fragment to display the details of the selected item.

You should take a look at the [Fragements](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) documentation to implement this in your application.

Answer (score -1):

Try Activity Group.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html

Comment: Please don't, if at all avoidable. ActivityGroup is deprecated and should not be used any more, and for good reasons. You can use Fragments even on pre-3.0 devices by using the support library.