# Positioning a graph using achartengine in an XML file

Tags: android, xml, achartengine

So, I want to make an application that can read in several groups of data and display a graph. My problem, is not loading the graph itself, I've gotten that to work, but I would like to display the graph in a particular UI. I would like a graph displayed, with 6 check boxes and a spinner below. Depending on what option the spinner chooses, the 6 check boxes will be different.

However, I have followed a few tutorials and they don't even require XML files. How can I implement my graph to have this, or how can I layout where I want the graph from achartengine to displayed in an XML file.

What I have:
[image]

What I want ( poor paint drawing but you get it :D ):

[image]

The a-f white boxes are supposed to be check boxes.

Also.....I know I should really post code with this, but there is NO xml file given for this graph, it is done completely in a simple Java class.

Comment: You can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't see that before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an FAQ in AChartEngine. The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692).

There is also an example in the demo project. You can download the ACE demo [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list). It also includes some code demonstrating how to embed a chart inside an XML layout.