# How can I draw aChartEngine pie chart in a table row

Tags: android, achartengine

Here is the code that I am using. I have removed the code that generates other information displayed in the row and have provided only the code related to the creation and addition of the pie chart. If I remove the line "layout.addView(mChartView);" then the table is produced and it show all the other information, but of course , it does not show the pie chart.

```
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow row = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    GlobalData global = ((GlobalData)getApplicationContext());
    for( int i = 0; i < global.getData(0).size(); i++){

        DataModel current = global.getData(0).get(i);

        row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow, table, false);
        row.setTag(i);
        row.setClickable(true);

        //pie chart
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        int[] values = {50, 100};
        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Market share");
        int k = 0;
        for (int value : values) {
            series.add("Section " + ++k, value);
        }

        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW };

        DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
        for (int color : colors) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(color);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(null, series, renderer);
        layout.addView(mChartView);

        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        table.addView(row);
```

This code snippet is located in the onCreate event of the view.

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Have you tried to search anything to related this?

Comment: First create a table. Then create a row within that table. Next create a cell within that row, and finally draw your pie chart using aChartEngine. Seriously though -- first: try. second: if you do not succeed, post what you have tried and what its results were when you ask for help. Skipping the first step is really not an option at stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, I have searched for answers to this in stackoverflow and elsewhere with no success. I can create a pie graph and display it on a view that is not a problem. This issue arises when I try and add the pie graph view to a table row during the inflation process. I will try and add some code now so you can see what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: (I do feel stupid); I had referenced the layout in the following manner

```
//pie chart
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

I should have

```
//pie chart
 RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.chart);
```

When I added row.findViewByID it all works

Wood for the trees problem Sorry for wasting your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try with a simpler approach first. Try with a `LinearLayout` and see if that is working and only afterwards try with a `TableLayout`. For embedding an AChartEngine inside a LinearLayout, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692).

Comment: Dan, Thank you. Yes I have tried that and Yes the charts are always displayed in a Liniarlayout. In fact for several views in my android app the charts all display well and the aChartEngine is superb. It is just the insertion of a chart into a row of a table that is giving me trouble. I think it may have to do with the context variable but I am not sure.