# How to draw muitiple bar charts in one activity in Android

Tags: android, bar-chart

I am working on Android Application which can show salary comparisons in a bar chart.

I need to display two charts in a same activity and I am successful in displaying one chart per one activity using `achartengine`.

I need Confirmation that is it possible to display two charts in one activity like this.If so please help me..

[image: salary chart]

Comment: I am not sure but may be Fragments helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely have 2 views added to your activity. Each view would contain a chart created with AChartEngine.

In order to see how to embed charts inside an activity, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692) post.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, I followed your way and i got it