# How to Draw custom Bar charts in Android

Tags: android, bar-chart

I am developing an application, in which there is a requirement for showing results in a Bar charts. I have tried developing charts using `AChartEngine` and `Google api` and many other apis. But my Requirement is to draw multiple charts in one Activity. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692).Its working fine. But when i try to set the background image for the whole screen, Its not working

Can Anybody help me please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just check this [`Bar Chart in Android With out any Built in jars`](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/bar-chart-in-android-with-out-any-built-in-jars/). Here you can draw charts without any built in jars. Its just simple Graph creation using the concept of setting the height for the textview in a ListView.

I implemented this by using the [Horizontal ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). Here you have the two double arrays with equal size of elements. And the graph will adjust according to the orientation(Portrait and landscape).

If you want more charts in one activity, you can implement another Horizontal Listview in the layout.

I hope this will help you....

Comment: I look at your blog. I am getting errors at the horizontal listview.. can you help me..

Comment: Just download the code from the [link](https://sites.google.com/site/ramkiranworks/customization/My%20Chart.zip?attredirects=0)

Answer (score 0):

i can help you with paid Library which is  nice
is called [aiCharts (Bar Charts)](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx)

or you should refer `GraphViewDemo` it is also anice and free libraray to make bar graph

[GraphViewDemo](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView-Demos)

Comment: I have tried these already. I get two charts in one activity, but my problem is that the background of the screen is not setting when i am using these api's. Can you help me pls

Comment: Well you can any day have 1 chart instead of 2

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a [blog post](http://binaryspells.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/android-recipes-bar-chart.html) on the subject. For one of my clients I created a compound view with an embedded bar chart. I did not find a simple and flexible library to achieve this, so I decided to go with custom views. To my surprise, it was simpler than I had expected: create a custom view that takes a colour and a percentage as attributes and use linear layouts to contain its instances, using layout_weight or a fixed layout_width to maintain proportions. I am very happy with the results.