# Why Is AChartEngine PieChart Not Displaying In Dialog?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dialog, achartengine

I'm a noob to android development and I am trying to display a pie chart in a dialog.  However, I cannot get the piechart to display.  I used the XYChartBuilder.java as my guide as suggested by this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a).  I used the achart demo xychart.xml to test my layout design and it worked perfectly with the demo.  But when i try to use the same xml configuration with my application i get an nullpointerexception saying android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled. The only change i made was to instantiate the ChartView when the dialog is opened via layoutinflater as opposed to during onResume in the demo.  When i change the chart linearlayout from a defined height of 200dp to "wrap_content" the exception isn't thrown.  I have included activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" /> in my manifest so that isn't the problem. The issue has to be something with the dialog.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <com.activity.GSCC.SegmentedRadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/segment_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/button_one"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@id/button_one"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:minWidth="40dip"
            android:text="Ledger"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="33dip"
            android:minWidth="40dip"
            android:text="Chart"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
    </com.activity.GSCC.SegmentedRadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="105dp" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Coin"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Qty."
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Oz."
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Value"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvcurrentcoin"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:text="CurrentCoin"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvcurrentqty"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CurrentQuantity"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvcurrentoz"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CurrentOunces"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvcurrentvalue"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CurrentValue"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nothing2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:maxWidth="100dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nothing"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTotalValue"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TOTAL:"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvportfoliovalue"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="CurrentValue"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12dp" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_values" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="@string/x" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/xValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:text="@string/y" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/yValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:enabled="false" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:text="@string/add" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chart"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" //Doesn't throw exception when set to "wrap content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/new_series"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/new_series" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinneradd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.77" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnermodify"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.70" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerdelete"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.77" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerchange"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.40" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSQLdeleteall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete All Entries" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

MY CODE

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sqliteexample2,null);

//CHART ADDITIONS
            if (mChartView == null) {
                  piechartlayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
                  mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(Activity.this, mDataset, mRenderer);
                  mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
                  mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);                     
                  mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                      double[] xy = mChartView.toRealPoint(0);
                      if (seriesSelection == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "No chart element was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                      } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this,
                            "Chart element in series index " + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex()
                                + " data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was clicked"
                                + " closest point value X=" + seriesSelection.getXValue() + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue()
                                + " clicked point value X=" + (float) xy[0] + ", Y=" + (float) xy[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                    }
                  });
                  mChartView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                      SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                      if (seriesSelection == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "No chart element was long pressed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        return false; // no chart element was long pressed, so let something
                        // else handle the event
                      } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Chart element in series index "
                            + seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex() + " data point index "
                            + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " was long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        return true; // the element was long pressed - the event has been
                        // handled
                      }
                    }
                  });
                  mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
                    public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
                      String type = "out";
                      if (e.isZoomIn()) {
                        type = "in";
                      }
                      System.out.println("Zoom " + type + " rate " + e.getZoomRate());
                    }

                    public void zoomReset() {
                      System.out.println("Reset");
                    }
                  }, true, true);
                  mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
                    public void panApplied() {
                      System.out.println("New X range=[" + mRenderer.getXAxisMin() + ", " + mRenderer.getXAxisMax()
                          + "], Y range=[" + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + ", " + mRenderer.getYAxisMax() + "]");
                    }
                  });
                  piechartlayout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                  boolean enabled = mDataset.getSeriesCount() > 0;
                  setSeriesEnabled(enabled);
                } else {
                  mChartView.repaint();
                }

            //////CHART ADDITIONS
                    mX = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.xValue);
                    mX.setEnabled(true);
                    mY = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.yValue);
                    mY.setEnabled(true);
                    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
                    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
                    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
                    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
                    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
                    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
                    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
                    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
                    mRenderer.setPointSize(10);
                    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);

                    mAdd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add);
                    mAdd.setEnabled(true);
                    mNewSeries = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.new_series);
                    mNewSeries.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                        String seriesTitle = "Series " + (mDataset.getSeriesCount() + 1);
                        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
                        mDataset.addSeries(series);
                        mCurrentSeries = series;
                        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
                        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
                        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
                        renderer.setFillPoints(true);
                        mCurrentRenderer = renderer;
                        setSeriesEnabled(true);
                      }
                    });


                    mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                        double x = 0;
                        double y = 0;
                        try {
                          x = Double.parseDouble(mX.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                          // TODO
                          mX.requestFocus();
                          return;
                        }
                        try {
                          y = Double.parseDouble(mY.getText().toString());
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                          // TODO
                          mY.requestFocus();
                          return;
                        }
                        mCurrentSeries.add(12, 0);
                        mX.setText("");
                        mY.setText("");
                        mX.requestFocus();
                        if (mChartView != null) {
                          mChartView.repaint();
                        }
                        Bitmap bitmap = mChartView.toBitmap();
                        try {
                          File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test" + index++ + ".png");
                          FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                      }
                    });
                    //END CHART ADDITIONS
```

FULL STACK TRACE (When i give layout containing chart a defined height of 100dp)

```
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:954)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:980)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:174)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1409)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2116)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1565)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1301)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1914)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-14 20:28:13.430: E/AndroidRuntime(26620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where is the code for this statement? Also, please post full stack trace. "I've tried tinkering with the "chart" LinearLayout by giving it values for width and height instead of just "wrap_content" but that only gives an exception java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto just posted my logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue before.  trying to use the zoom for achartengine is impossible inside a dialog.  try commenting out setzoomvisible and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first download the entire AChartEngine demo program and run it as it is. Then, you can start modifying it in small steps until you get it to a version that you need.