# android achartengine set chart in custom layout

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using achartengine for timechart using demo given (TimechartIntent). I want to set chart inside my custom xml layout. Any idea?

Comment: Whats problem to add chart with ChartFactory?

Comment: I want to add xml layout with my chart.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692

Answer (score 0):

Add `Linearlayout` to your xml layout and put your chart in this `LinearLayout`