# where can i put layout when i have a intent?

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine

i want to use chart in android, i use [this](http://www.achartengine.org/) framework 
below class will use when start:

```
public class ChartDemo extends ListActivity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent=  new SalesStackedBarChart().execute(this);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
```

view detail of class ChartDemo [here](http://achartengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/r425/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/ChartDemo.java)

detail class SalesStackedBarChart [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/SalesStackedBarChart.java?r=450)

when do startActivity(intent), i have a chart like this: [image]
but i want use this chart into a layout with button, textview....how do i do?
thank!

Comment: do you mean that you don't want the chart to fire up when the activity loads, but instead to be shown when the user taps a button?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) example. It shows you exactly what you need.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you're asking how to kick this off with a button (instead of onCreate) then you'll need to put your startActivity code into a button onClick handler...

The easiest way to do this is like this:

XML...

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onclick="openChart"
android:text="Open Chart"
/>
```

and then in your Activity code

```
public void openChart(View v){
    Intent intent=  new SalesStackedBarChart().execute(this);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i want create a acvitity with a layout xml file include this chart

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand specifically what you're asking. I suspect it's a language barrier. I realize it's not easy, but could you please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want create a activity with main.xml like in this image: http://nu7.upanh.com/b6.s33.d3/4a7d1c82ee3404e3758e99c209ebdaf5_52507717.nouquodi3v2.png

this layout have chart

Answer (score 0):

do the following steps:

1. Create a layout with button.
2. Include that custom chart view into the layout.

and do what ever you want.