# show more than one chart in achartengine

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to strictly have 3 charts in only one page but the video files associate with AChartEngine shows the way to display 1chart per page with java codes
(http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=AChartEngine)
I have searched to find the way to put every chart in linearlayout and eventually find:
 [Android: I am using AChartEngine library for graphs, but not able to integrate achartengine's graph view with android xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a)

but it seems with the latest version 1.01 it doesn't run

Could you please let me know whether there is a way to show 3chart in only one page or not?If yes, could you please let me know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692) example. It shows you how to embed a chart inside a view. If you create 3 separate `LinearLayout`s, you will be able to add 3 charts, one per each `LinearLayout`.