# Integrate an achartengine in popup window

Tags: android, achartengine, popupwindow

I am trying to integrate a chart which is updated dynamically. My only problem is that I want to open that chart in a popup window. Could someone please share some infos or links with me where I can find something concrete?

Comment: Use custom dialog fragment.

Comment: See an example of embedding a chart inside any custom view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062161/android-i-am-using-achartengine-library-for-graphs-but-not-able-to-integrate-a/4079692#4079692